# Is there any operand type that could be used for this?

Tags: php, for-loop

Look at this table:

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
for($i = 1;$i<99;$i++)
{
  $i = intval($i);

  if ($i / 3  == intval($i / 3))
  {
    echo "<tr><td>this is third tr</td></tr>";
  }
  else
  {
     echo "<tr><td>this is first or second</td></tr>";
  }
}
```

output is something like

```
this is first or second
this is first or second
this is third tr
this is first or second
this is first or second
this is third tr
this is first or second
this is first or second
this is third tr
```

is there more elegant way to detect ALWAYS third tr?

Comment: what do you mean by "detect ALWAYS third tr"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you looking for something like:

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
for($i = 1;$i<99;$i++){
  if ($i % 3  == 0){
    echo "<tr><td>this is third tr</td></tr>";
  }else{
     echo "<tr><td>this is first or second</td></tr>";
  };
};
echo "</table>";
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: nice :p beat me by couple secs

Comment: nice :p I was trying it with this operand yesterday but failed :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)...

```
if ( ! (i % 3))
```

It will return the remainder of the division. You need the parenthesis because of the order of precedence.

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/9mbQ5PNL).

Also `$i = intval($i)` is redundant. `$i` is already an integer.

Comment: @Nicklamort: I don't get it? :S